# Jena someValuesFrom error - {E201} rdf:resource not allowed as attribute here

Tags: java, jena, owl

I'm fairly new to learning the semantic web, so to facilitate learning, I chose to write an ontology about something I'm fairly familiar with, video games.

So I think I'm starting to understand this a little bit, but there are still a few issues. My general thought here is that there are essentially 4 platforms. Granted this is grossly simplified (instead of different consoles, just list the companies that make a console a game is playable on.) Anyways, the problem that I'm having stems from the line:

```
<owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Platforms"/>
```

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with it, I've tried with and without the '#' character, but Jena is giving me this error on parsing it (if I comment it out, it parses just fine):

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: {E201} rdf:resource not allowed as attribute here.
```

I have a feeling that I don't fully understand owl:someValuesFrom, and most of the reference ontologies that I've looked at seem to use it in a similar context. I'm almost sure that I'm overlooking something simple so maybe more eyes would help, but any and all help appreciated. I'd be happy to post more of the ontology if that'd be required as well.

The context of it is:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Platforms">
    <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <owl:Thing rdf:about="#PC"/>
        <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Playstation"/>
        <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Xbox"/>
        <owl:Thing rdf:about="#Nintendo"/>
    </owl:oneOf>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:ID="Platform">
    <rdfs:label>Platform</rdfs:label>
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Platforms"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
</owl:Class>
```

The Java code for opening/reading the Ontology is:

```
    try
    {
        // open input file stream
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFile);

        // create a new model, then read the OWL file into it
        model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF, null);
        model.read(inputFile);      
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Additional information:
I'm using Jena 2.10.0 (latest) and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not immediately sure if this is the cause of the parse error you're seeing, but your restriction is missing a bit: it says what it restricts to (namely some values from the class `Platforms`), but it doesn't say what property is being restricted.

You need something like this:

```
<owl:Restriction>
     <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#platformType" />
     <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Platforms"/>
</owl:Restriction>
```

In addition, the restriction can not be immediately part of the `owl:Class` element. You need either a `rdfS:subClassOf` element or a `owl:equivalentClass` element around it.

Also, a tip: don't write your ontologies by hand in RDF/XML syntax. Either use an ontology editor such as Protege or TopBraid, or switch to a different, more easy to read/edit syntax, such as Turtle. Trust me on this, things will become a lot easier if you do.

For example, your (corrected) ontology in Turtle syntax reads:

```
:Platforms a owl:Class ;
           owl:oneOf ( :PC :PlayStation :Xbox :Nintendo ) .

:Platform a owl:Class ;
          rdfs:label "Platform";
          rdfs:subClassOf [ a owl:Restriction ;
                            owl:onProperty :platformType ;
                            owl:someValuesFrom :Platforms ] .
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm really new to this and there seems to be very little/sparse documentation. I tried using Protege, but the Ontology it spits out seems to be different, and Jena doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Protege should be able to produce an OWL ontology that Jena (or any other RDF toolkit) can process. If you run into issues with that, ask around on the protege or jena user lists.

Comment: Really late check in here, but I wanted to give an update. After much time spent on this, I ultimately abandoned this 'project' to focus on other more pressing assignments. Finally marked your response as an answer, sorry for taking so long!